# django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser to User

Tags: django, django-authentication

I need to get the user info but I only have `request.user` which gives me a `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser`. I know that AnonymousUser's id, username, ... are empty. How can I get the User's info?

Comment: The user doesn't have any info, they're anonymous. (Not authenticated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't work with AnonymousUser directly, this class is only necessary to be the default user in Django requests.

If you have the user id, do this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

[... other code there ...]

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise PermissionDenied

[... other code there ...]
```